# AWS API Gateway with dynamic URL path parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've got an API with an integration to S3 to serve static files. My resource is quite simple in that I only require the filename to serve the file, like so:

`/api/v1/{file}`

However this requires the consumer to know the exact filename, i.e.

`/api/v1/purple.json`

I want to make this a little more dynamic. Since my files are all JSON, I want the consumer to not have to provide the `.json` suffix. Is this currently possible with the URL path parameters? I know I can use `method.request.path.file` to access the `purple` value, but can I append `.json` to it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway does not currently allow for concatenation of values in parameter mapping. This is a feature other customers have requested and is on our backlog.